# How to decide convolution layers' filter?

Tags: tensorflow

When you guys make a convolution layer includes hidden layers, how to decide parameters? like filter, stride and even the number of convolution layers? I know the meaning of each parameter, but if I have to make from the start, how can I?

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow, this question will be to broad for here. the answer should be that you should take a course about neural networks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to below links to have better understanding of CNNs and how to make use of them.

http://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks/

https://medium.com/@RaghavPrabhu/understanding-of-convolutional-neural-network-cnn-deep-learning-99760835f148

https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2018/12/guide-convolutional-neural-network-cnn/

https://towardsdatascience.com/deciding-optimal-filter-size-for-cnns-d6f7b56f9363

Comment: I really appreciate your comment.